# Does Pyinstaller's "runtime-tmpdir" parameter affects the performance of the exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

I am creating a one file executable and curious about the runtime-tmpdir parameter. As the one file always creates temp files in OS temp dir whenever opened, I want to change that with this option. But I am a bit worried before using this parameter as in the [docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html) of Pyinstaller it is mentioned- "Please use this option only if you know what you are doing".

Its a bit silly question but will it affect the performance or any other system files?

Comment: I think you should explain *why* you think you need to change it. Changing it won't make startup any faster on the next run. Your `. exe` will still unpack itself into a fresh folder under the location you specify.

Comment: @BoarGules Because sometimes if the program crashes or we close the parent window(cmd) then all the files stays in the os temp folder creating a huge mess. We have to manually clear those, which is not good for the end user. If I use the runtime-tempdir it will not clutter in the os temp and I can also add an option to clear temp within the application to delete that safely. Even the user can get rid of it easily if the temp folder is inside the exe folder. I just wanted to know if it will affect the performance.

Comment: Fair enough. One solution that occurs to me is to find the location of the current temp dir, persist in in a config file of some sort, and have the application look for and delete that folder on startup the next time. You could even keep the last few folder names to be on the safe side. That would work with no intervention no matter where you choose to put the files, and you would also have a record of where they were, helpful if things don't go to plan.

Comment: @BoarGules Good idea, to my experience Pyinstaller is only good if you are making an installer. The direct one dir is messy, the one file is slow that creates temp.                       
Is there any other alternative that can make clean dir and exe?

Comment: No. Python is not a compiled language and can't be turned into machine code. The best available is something that will install the application and its dependencies as bytecode, and Python, then launch the interpreter to run it. An alternative to `pyinstaller` is `py2exe` which was a casualty of the Python 2/3 transition and went dormant, but has recently been revived. The approach is identical. I find `pyinstaller`'s logs more helpful when things go wrong. Though they are sometimes so long as to make anyone's heart sink.

Comment: @BoarGules Finally after requesting to fix the crashed temp folder issue (one-file), they have successfully fixed the issue in the new Pyinstaller v5.3 release.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the mention didn't bother me. It should not affect performance, but it is possible for errors, depending on how your code is structured. I use "--runtime-tmpdir" and I'm fine :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).